# What are all possible dot products?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been trying to know what other possible inner products can be defined for several vector spaces this is more of less what I wanted to know when I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1847997/25805) but at this time, I thought that there could be a huge number of dot products but after trying to create new ones, it doesn't seems to be the case.

So we have for vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$ the following dot product:

$$\langle (u_1, \dots ,u_n ) , (v_1 \dots , v_n ) \rangle = u_1 v_1 + \dots + u_n v_n $$

And for continuous functions, the following dot product:

$$\left\langle u , v \right\rangle = \int_a^b u(x) v(x) d x$$

I have tried to define a lot of other dot products for these cases and for every one of them, one of the [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Properties) failed. I guess the most *promissing* example for the first case would be using some permutation of the coordinates:

$$\langle u,v \rangle := u_1 v_n  + \dots + u_n v_1 $$

But if fails. The most promissing trial for the second case was:

$$\langle f,g \rangle :=|f(a)|+|g(a)|$$

But it also fails. Now I'm interested in the general question:

- A dot product is a map $\Bbb{V} \times \Bbb{V} \to \Bbb{R} $ such that these [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Properties) are not violated, what is the number of possible dot products that can be defined? Is it possible to somehow *sweep* all the possible dot products and have a glimpse at their *"structure"*?

What seems somewhat surprising to me is that it seems that these properties somehow impose a very strong binding in the possible dot products and I am starting to think that those dot products are unique. Is this the case?

Comment: For a finite-dimensional vector space, every positive definite matrix corresponds to an inner product.

Comment: Every inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ takes the form $\langle u, Av \rangle$ where $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix uniquely determined by the inner product.

Comment: Since every real symmetric positive definite matrix can be diagonalized to a matrix with positive diagonals using orthogonal matrices. After suitable scaling of the basis, every inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equivalent to ordinary inner product.

Comment: Good. Does this also tell anything about the case for continuous functions? I'm sorry, this is not immediate for me.

Comment: @achillehui In fact, Gram-Schmidt constructs an isometry from an arbitrary inner product to the standard one. (An alternate way of saying the same thing you did.)

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon yes, it is equivalent. I just try to present the statement in a more geometrical manner.

Comment: @achillehui Why positive definite? I don't see a positiveness property among the OP ones..

Comment: @Exodd positive definiteness is part of the definition of [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition).

Comment: @achillehui Funny, I find the version I stated more geometric. Timtowtdi, I guess. :)